# Firefox won't scroll to start/end of this page with home/end keys

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, css

I'm using Firefox 13.0 on Ubuntu 11.10 and when accessing [this web page](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Roles), with JavaScript enabled, the <kbd>home</kbd> and <kbd>end</kbd> keys will not scroll to the start/end of the document (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>home</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>end</kbd> work).

The page does *not* use frames.  It does use a lot of CSS, including a scrolling sidebar.

Is there a CSS tweak I could use to fix this?  I'm using the [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) add-on to override a few other annoyances and could add in a fix if possible.

Why is FireFox behaving like this?

FWIW, I did check to see if I'd activated caret browsing. The behavior noted occurs with caret browsing *off*.

Comment: FF beta (14.0.1) on windows and it working fine here.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it is not reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you accidentally activated Caret Browsing by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>. Try pressing <kbd>F7</kbd> again to deactivate caret browsing. If that is the solution, you may want to turn on the warning that you're entering Caret Browsing mode again by going to about:config and looking for the following preference:

```
accessibility.warn_on_browsewithcaret
```

Set its value to true. This way Firefox will prompt you for permission the next time you press <kbd>F7</kbd>.

Comment: Nope.  I checked for this though.